# Why does Mike replace Jimmy and Kim's fridge?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-call-saul

In Better Call Saul, season 6, ep 8, Point and Shoot

> After Lalo is shot dead by Gus,

Mike sends Kim home and replaces their fridge with a new one.
Why does Mike do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they disposed of Howard's body by taking it away in the old refrigerator.

> Back at Jimmy and Kim’s apartment, Jimmy sits on his bed as one of Mike’s men begins clearing out his fridge. Howard’s body is now covered with a blanket and he looks on in quiet resignation to the situation unfolding. When Kim enters the apartment, they share an emotional hug as Mike walks in with a few more men wielding a new refrigerator.

> Just as he goes to exit their bedroom, Mike opens the door enough for Jimmy to see men loading Howard’s body into their existing fridge

Comment: right, I was thinking if there was a bullet hole (Lalo shot Howard with) in the fridge and they removed it because of it.

Comment: @YuZhang I think you missed the scene where Mike's men were stuffing Howard's corpse inside the fridge.

Comment: The bullet hole is in the wall, there's actually a shot of it.